# Android app crashes when button pressed in new activity

Tags: android, database, button, logcat

I am making an Android app that holds a list of countries in an SQLite database. The initial screen displays the list. when you press "Edit List" a new activity starts where you can enter in a new country or delete the whole list. The app works perfectly until I click a button in my second activity. If I enter in my new country and click add, the app give me a message that it has stopped, yet the country still adds to my database. It's the same with my delete all button. I get an error in my logcat but still it deletes all. Here is my code for the class that the error occurs:

```
public class EditList extends Activity
{
    private DBManager db;
    Cursor cursor;
    EditText editCountry, editYear;
    Button add, delete, back;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editCountry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcountry);
        editYear = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edityear);
        add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backmain);

        //Open database and fill it with content, then close it
        db = new DBManager(this);
        db.openToWrite();

        add.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);
        delete.setOnClickListener(buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener);

        //------
        Log.i("Test", "back to main");

        //go back to the main list screen
        back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backmain);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                db.close();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    //insert new country button
    Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            int year = Integer.parseInt(editYear.getText().toString());
            String country = editCountry.getText().toString();

            db.insert(year, country);

            updateList();

            //clear text fields after use
            editYear.setText(null);
            editCountry.setText(null);
        }
    };

    //delete all button
    Button.OnClickListener buttonDeleteAllOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            db.deleteAll();

            updateList();
        }
    };

    private void updateList()
    {
        cursor.requery();
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat errors that occur:

```
02-07 22:32:31.117: D/AndroidRuntime(2633): Shutting down VM
02-07 22:32:31.117: W/dalvikvm(2633): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4e35908)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at com.mypackage.msdassignment.EditList.updateList(EditList.java:90)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at com.mypackage.msdassignment.EditList.access$1(EditList.java:88)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at com.mypackage.msdassignment.EditList$1.onClick(EditList.java:68)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-07 22:32:31.158: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like cursor is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never instantiating your cursor.  You declare it and then you use it.  That will fail.